# There are no GPS data after connecting to the server

Tags: arduino, gps, arduino-uno, at-command

I'm trying to get GPS data and send it to the server via socket.
I'm using Arduino Uno and GPS/GSM module A7 Ai-Thinker.
And for Internet I use Ethernet shield connected to Wi-Fi router.

But I got trouble when I joined getting GPS data and sending it.
Separately that functions work fine. How I start A7, there is a loop where I type AT commands and send it to A7. About socket, I want to set connection at start function and keep it alive all the time.

But the problem is that when I initialized A7 and set socket connection, I go to the loop function and after first iteration there are no data at A7.
If I try to set connection with server first, and start A7 after it, A7 doesn't react to AT commands.

How can I keep connection with my server and don't lost connection with A7?

Code:

```cpp
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

//-------------------------------------------------------
static const int RXPin = 10, TXPin = 11;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 4800;
const String START_GPS = "START_GPS";

TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial gps_serial(RXPin, TXPin);

//-------------------------------------------------------
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "192.168.0.100";
int port = 8090;

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
EthernetClient client;
//-------------------------------------------------------

void initGpsConnection();
void startGps();

void initSocketConnection();
void sendData();


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();

  initSocketConnection();
  initGpsConnection();

  sendData();
}

void loop()
{
  while (gps_serial.available() > 0) {
    if (gps.encode(gps_serial.read()))  {
      displayInfo();
      //delay(1000);
    }
  }

  if (millis() > 120000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
  {
    Serial.println(F("No GPS detected: check wiring."));
    //while(true);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Socket connection has been lost.");
    client.stop();

    //while (true);
  }
}

void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(F(","));
    Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date/Time: "));
  if (gps.date.isValid()) {
    Serial.print(gps.date.month() + "/" gps.date.day() + "/" + gps.date.year();
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F(" "));
  if (gps.time.isValid()) { 
    Serial.print(gps.time.hour() + ":" + gps.time.minute() + ":" + gps.time.second());
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }
  Serial.println();
}



void initGpsConnection() {
  Serial.println("In init gps");
  gps_serial.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println("after gps begin");
  delay(1000);
  startGps();

  Serial.println("GPS connection has been set");
}


void startGps() {
  Serial.println("Enter at commands, after that enter `start_gps`");
  String response = "";

  while (true) {
    if (gps_serial.available()) {
      Serial.write(gps_serial.read());
    }
    if (Serial.available()) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      response += c;

      if (response.indexOf(START_GPS) > 0)
        break;

      gps_serial.write(c);
    }
  }
}

void initSocketConnection() {
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, port)) {
    Serial.println("Connection with server has been set");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection with server has been failed");
  }
}


void sendData(){
  client.print("TEst ard");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at `A7` connection. It was connected via 10, 11 pins at `Ethernet shield`. But 10-13 pins are reserved by `A7`. It's just needed connect `A7` vie 8, 9 or others pins.